# Encrypt cache OkHttp android

Tags: android, caching, okhttp

Because of cache class is set to final, I can not write my own implementation and I am needing to encrypt the cache because is sensitive data. I'd try with an interceptor but there is nothing like a `CacheResponseInterceptor` to encrypt and decrypt it. How can I do this using `OkHttp`?

Comment: I suspect that this is not directly possible, based on [this issue comment](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1605#issuecomment-162013369). You may need to disable OkHttp's caching and do your own caching.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, but how? Is it possible to build my own cache response? If so i'd do it in an interceptor i guess.

Comment: No, I mean do your own caching outside of OkHttp. You disable OkHttp's cache. When, you get a response, you write that and relevant metadata (e.g., cache headers) to your encrypted data store. When you later need to make a request, you check your encrypted data store first, before touching OkHttp, and only use OkHttp if your own cache is stale or does not have this data. This is a pain, and [I added your request to the OkHttp 4.0 wishlist](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2903), FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CommonsWare That's not as practical as i wanted to but finally we decided not to encrypt it. The data is not sensitive enough to waste time in this workaround. Thank you for adding it to the wishlist. I hope they'll include it in the next release.